# Lebesgue measure compact symmetric intervals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$  be a measure on $L_m$ , ($m \ge 1$) - $\sigma$ - algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets, such that its values on compact, symmetric intervals (cubes) are equal to Lebesgue measure of those cubes. Then $\mu = \mathcal{L}^m$.

Could you tell me how to prove this observation?

I know we can define Lebesgue measure by symmetric cubes, but I am not sure how to use it here.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Could you write everything you wrote in your comment as an answer? I don't know how about you, but I cannot see any comments. I can only see a preview of what you wrote in the "recent inbox messages" bar.

Comment: Use regularity: For any bounded measurable set $M$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there are sets $K, U$ such that $K$ is compact, $U$ is open, $K \subseteq M \subseteq U$ and $U \backslash K$ has Lebesgue measure less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you write something more? Lebesgue measure of a set is $\inf \  [ \ { \sum _{i \in \mathbb{N}} vol (I_i) \ | \  \{I_i } - \text{ a sequence of compact intervals covering a set } ]$ So what I need to know is that the measures are equal for bounded sets (but I'm not sure how that follows from your comment) and them somehow show this for all Lebesgue measurable sets...

Comment: Denote Lebesgue measure by $\lambda$. Given any bounded measurable set $M$, use the above comment to show that $|\mu(M) - \lambda(M)| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Note that your assumption implies that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ also agree on every compact set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fact is false. Let $g(x)=1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $x\ge 0$ and $g(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ otherwise. Let define $\mu$ in $R$ as follows: $\mu(A)=\int_{A}g(x)d \cal{L}^1(x)$ for all Lebesgue measurable subset $A \subseteq R$. It is obvious that $\mu$  satisfies all conditions above but $\mu \neq \cal{L}^1$.

Comment: Your $\mu$ exceeds Lebesgue measure on (0, 1)$.

Comment: It depends on what is meant by "symmetric cube" in the question. If it means symmetric under reflection through the origin, then this counterexample is correct. I think the question could be clearer.

Comment: Each cube is symmetric with respect to its center of mass.  I assume under symmetric cube a cube which is symmertic with respect to  the origin. If under symmetric cubes we assume cubes then the answer is trivial -yes. The Lebesgue measure is uniquelly  defined by its values on cubes.

Comment: Each compact cube is symmetric under reflection thought its center of mass.  It is well known that the Lebesgue measure is uniquelly  defined by its values on cubes. It is sufficient to take only all cubes with rational length.

Comment: Yes, I meant cubes = symmetric intervals. That is cubes which are symmetric with respect to the origin. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: For every symmetric (w.r.t. origin) cube $[-a,a]$ (equivalently, $[-a,a]$ symmetric interval in $R^1$) we have $\mu([-a,a])=\cal{L}^1([-a,a])$ but $\mu([0,1])>\cal{L}^1([0,1])$ which implies that $\mu \neq \cal{L}^1$.